# Typesetting recommendation for pluses and minuses within number range

Tags: luatex

For a standard number range, using "--" works well e.g. "You open 1NT with 15--17 points".

But I have cases where I need to write e.g. "The 1NT response shows a good 8 to a bad 10 points" very concisely to fit into smallish table cell.  I initially tried 8(+)--10(-) as a notation for that but I didn't like the look of it very much.

I'm currently kerning and changing font size, but there are cases where it doesn't look very good.  For example,

```
\newcommand{\Bm}{{\kern-0.2ex\larger -}}%
```

used as 9\Bm--10\Bp to mean "from a bad 9-point to a good 10-point hand".

One other use case is that it should also look well when followed by \ieme{} together with a card symbol

```
\newcommand{\Cs}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\mbox{\color{red}\varheart}}}%
```

4\Bp\ieme{}\Cs{} being shorthand for "at least 4 hearts".

Any thoughts on how best to tackle this in LaTeX?

Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper, % Stock and paper size.
11pt, % Type size.
book,
onecolumn, % Only one column of text on a page.
openany, % A chapter may start on either a recto or verso page.
dvipsnames % To prevent xcolor clashes
]{memoir}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}%
\usepackage[normal]{threeparttable}%
\usepackage{fdsymbol}% 
\usepackage{relsize}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%

\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varspade}{\mathord}{extraup}{185}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varheart}{\mathord}{extraup}{184}% heart
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vardiamond}{\mathord}{extraup}{182}% diamond
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varclub}{\mathord}{extraup}{186}%

\newcommand{\Ps}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\mbox{\varspade}}}%
\newcommand{\Cs}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\mbox{\color{red}\varheart}}}%
\newcommand{\Ks}{\resizebox{1.5ex}{!}{\mbox{\color{red}\vardiamond}}}%
\newcommand{\Ts}{\resizebox{1.75ex}{!}{\mbox{\varclub}}}%
\newcommand{\Bp}{{\kern-0.2ex +}}%
\newcommand{\Bm}{{\kern-0.2ex\larger -}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{threeparttable}[t]
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}}
Est &Ouest  & \bfseries Signification\\
\toprule
1m  &   &\\  
\cmidrule(r){1-2}
    &1M &M 4\ieme, 5\Bp  H, 1\Ps{} nie 4 \Cs{} ;\\  
    &1SA    &Sans M 4\ieme{}, 8\Bp--10\Bm H sur 1\Ts{}, 6--10 H sur 1\Ks{} ; \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming this is for describing bidding conventions in bridge?

Comment: Yes, specifically in French but the same issue in English.

Comment: Though I don't have any idea what you want, you should still not post code snippets but a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`.

Comment: Case in point: the \ieme you use is french babel... not at all evident for English speakers

Comment: “How would you format this?” is an opinion-based question.  Voting to close.

Comment: What about `$8^{+}--10^{-}$` ? Hmm, I guess @remco is suggesting something quite similar this:) So, +1!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like

```
8\textsuperscript{\tiny+}--10\textsuperscript{\large -} H
```

to indicate the point range (hidden inside a suitable macro definition, of course).
Also, the '\ieme' in your suggestion "4\Bp\ieme{}\Cs{}" looks a bit superfluous to me (unless you have a possibility of confusion elsewhere).

It's hard to answer this more precisely, as we don't have all your notational conventions (and I don't know what's common bridge notation in France, it's the small differences that are tricky).